# Failed to create AR Session Android Sceneform

Tags: android, android-emulator, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to creating a simple AR application using AR Core and the Sceneform Sdk. I am using Android Studio Emulator for testing my application. I have also follwed the HelloAr Sample code of Sceneform sdk. But there is an error showing at the logcat like this.

```
2019-05-04 14:27:15.942 5172-5172/com.example.arcoredemo E/native: status.cc:156 generic::internal: Physical cameras don't match device profile. 0 expected back facing:CameraDirection::kRearFacing actual back facing:CameraDirection::kFrontFacing
2019-05-04 14:27:15.943 5172-5172/com.example.arcoredemo E/native: session_create_implementation_shared.cc:1544 Failed to initilize the data source - -2
2019-05-04 14:27:15.946 5172-5172/com.example.arcoredemo E/native: session_create_implementation_shared.cc:1545 CreateLiveSessionWithMostDependencies returning ArStatusErrorSpace::AR_ERROR_FATAL: .
2019-05-04 14:27:15.963 5172-5172/com.example.arcoredemo I/native: feature_combo_node.cc:176 Cleared scoped_image buffers in feature_combo.
2019-05-04 14:27:15.966 5172-5172/com.example.arcoredemo I/native: android_camera.cc:730 Reset cleanly got to CLOSED state for camera 0
2019-05-04 14:27:15.972 5172-5172/com.example.arcoredemo I/native: session_create_implementation.cc:148 ArSession_createWithSettingsImplementation_private returning ArStatusErrorSpace::AR_ERROR_FATAL: .
2019-05-04 14:27:15.972 5172-5195/com.example.arcoredemo V/third_party/redwood/base/jni_common/jni_helper.cc: ~JniHelper: about to detach thread (Called from line 281).
2019-05-04 14:27:15.973 5172-5195/com.example.arcoredemo V/third_party/redwood/base/jni_common/jni_helper.cc: ~JniHelper: detached thread (Called from line 281).
2019-05-04 14:27:15.981 5172-5172/com.example.arcoredemo E/StandardArFragment: Error: Failed to create AR session
    com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableException
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.initializeSession(BaseArFragment.java:356)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:311)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2498)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1501)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:3241)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:538)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:527)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:172)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.throwExceptionFromArStatus(Session.java:134)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.nativeCreateSessionAndWrapperWithFeatures(Native Method)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.<init>(Session.java:19)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.createSessionWithFeatures(BaseArFragment.java:381)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.createSession(BaseArFragment.java:370)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.initializeSession(BaseArFragment.java:344)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:311) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2498) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1501) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:3241) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:538) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:527) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:172) 
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7317) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Hello Ar Activity where I am creating initializing and creating the ar session.

```
    private static final String TAG = HelloArActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final double MIN_OPENGL_VERSION = 3.0;

    private ArFragment arFragment;
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})
    // CompletableFuture requires api level 24
    // FutureReturnValueIgnored is not valid
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        if (!checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(this)) {
            return;
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_ar);
        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ux_fragment);

        // When you build a Renderable, Sceneform loads its resources in the background while returning
        // a CompletableFuture. Call thenAccept(), handle(), or check isDone() before calling get().
       arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {
           Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
           MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(this,new Color(android.graphics.Color.RED))
                   .thenAccept(material -> {
                       ModelRenderable renderable  = ShapeFactory.makeSphere(1.0f,new Vector3(0f,1f,1f),material);
                       AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                       anchorNode.setRenderable(renderable);
                       arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
                   });
       });
    }

    /**
     * Returns false and displays an error message if Sceneform can not run, true if Sceneform can run
     * on this device.
     *
     * <p>Sceneform requires Android N on the device as well as OpenGL 3.0 capabilities.
     *
     * <p>Finishes the activity if Sceneform can not run
     */
    public static boolean checkIsSupportedDeviceOrFinish(final Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires Android N or later");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires Android N or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
        String openGlVersionString =
                ((ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                        .getDeviceConfigurationInfo()
                        .getGlEsVersion();
        if (Double.parseDouble(openGlVersionString) < MIN_OPENGL_VERSION) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 later");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Sceneform requires OpenGL ES 3.0 or later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with the code. But the problem is with the Android studio emulator. The emulator is not showing the virtual scene. I updated the android emulator and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have this in AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6ZTS.png)